# Domain propagation to all URLs on my WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, url

I installed a wordpress site on digitalocean and made all the DNS notes and it is completed according to https://www.whatsmydns.net/. However, the only page that has the domain name and the homepage, the other pages and posts have the IP address. Can anyone tell me what it could be, please?

Comment: No, we can't. You don't tell us anything about the site, or the configuration - not even the address. Sorry, we don't know how you've configured things.

Comment: I installed OpenLiteSpeed ​​WordPress 6.2.2 on the digital ocean server and made the DNS type "A".

Then I installed the domain and SSL via terminal, and from then on only the root domain works, the other pages have IP.

The website link is opropages.com.

Sorry for the little information, I'm learning.

Comment: I also added the codes to wp-config.php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );

also in funcitions.php the update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A record for the domain will cover all of the site. If the additional WordPress pages are coming up as IP addresses, if when you click a link on your site the place it goes to is an IP address, then almost certainly there is an issue with the WordPress setup. On your admin page, go to Settings | Permalinks and make sure one of the permalink types is selected - I usually choose `Post name` or `Month and name` as being the most search-engine friendly. If trying to go to a permalink does not work, if you can't type in `http://sitename.com/pagename` but can type in `http://12.34.56.78/pagename` and have it work, there's a problem with your WordPress install; go to your admin page, Dashboard | Updates, and either select Reinstall or Update WordPress (the current version is 6.3.2 so it likely will want to update).

I think the root of your problem, actually, is that you created the domain after you installed WordPress. Because the domain didn't exist when WordPress was installed, it set itself up internally to use the IP. In the worst case, now that you have the domain set up, you may have to remove and reinstall WordPress.

Comment: Hello.

Actually, the solution I found was to reinstall Wordpress with the DNS already propagated.

Thank you for your attention!